# Using <include> with <merge> in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup, android-constraintlayout

I am having trouble using tags `<include>` and `<merge>` inside a ConstraintLayout.

I want to create a flat view hierarchy (hence Constraints) but still have elements that are reusable. So I use `<include>` in my layout and `<merge>` in the included layouts to avoid having nested layouts (especially avoiding nested ConstraintLayouts)

So I wrote this:
Parent layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/review_1"
        layout="@layout/view_movie_note"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/review_2"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_movie_note"
        android:id="@+id/review_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/review_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this view_movie_note :

```
<merge>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note_origin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/five_star_view_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:contentPaddingTop="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/note_origin">

        <FiveStarsView
            android:id="@+id/five_star_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:contentPaddingLeft="15dp"
        app:contentPaddingRight="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/note_origin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</merge>
```

I am expecting this

[image: I am expecting this]

Instead I got this

[image: Instead I get this]

Clearly the constraints that I put in the `<include>` tag are overriden by the constraints in the included layout.

Is this the expected behaviour ? If yes, how are we supposed to keep a flat layout using `<include>` and ConstraintLayout ?

Comment: It is expected behaviour. All the included views will be placed in parent view without any separate parent view group. You have card view with width as match_constraints and left and right constraint w.r.t parent and therefore, will occupy entire width

Comment: Please note, we see that issue in setting 0dp to content size. But in case of setting wrap content (for ex.), included constraints don't apply to merged Views with their settings. So how to solve this issue, without reseting all constraints in runtime.

Comment: I've added a bounty to your question and created an issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115695764 with a suggestion on how to handle merge for constraint layout, feel free to star it

Comment: Thanks @DanieleSegato it really got more attention this way. Unfortunately I was on holiday and your bounty expired... The answers only address the "why this is not working" part of the question but miss the real point which is : "How can we have reusable components and a flat layout ?" I guess we don't have a perfect solution yet and if I have to chose, I take reusable components over a perfectly flat layout any day. I starred your issue.

Answer (score 52):

## Short answer

**The best move will be replacing `<merge>` block with a (nested) `ConstraintLayout`** rather than using redundant layout structure.

---

> ConstraintLayout is great but it doesn't work well with composition
>   and separation of responsibilities of each piece

That is wrong. **`ConstraintLayout` does work well with reusing layouts.** Any layout in which all child views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, behaves exactly like this. This is true even for `RelativeLayout`.

## Then, where is the problem?

Let's take a closer look at what [`<merge>`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge) is.

The doc says

> The `<merge/>` tag helps eliminate redundant view groups in your view
>   hierarchy when including one layout within another.

It will have the same effect as replacing the `<include>` element with the contents of `<merge>` block. In other words, the views in the `<merge/>` block is directly placed to the parent layout without an intermediate view group. Therefore, the constraints of the `<include>` element is completely ignored.

In this particular example, the views in the including layout is added two times to the parent as the second one on top of another.

## Conclusion

Layout resource files are intended to be used independently. To qualify the term reusable, it should not depend on it's parent (The view group in which it will be added in future). 
It would be looking okay if you had to include the layout only one time. But `</merge>` won't be a good idea in that case too because you can't place it in any different layout in a different position.

Obviously, flat layout hierarchies have better performance. However, sometimes we may have to sacrifice it.

Comment: Good answer which is perfectly tied up with the conclusion/discussion where the tradeoff is explained which gives the reader a sort of confidence in their choice of applying the tip in the post.

Answer (score 7):

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) says

> The `<merge />` tag helps eliminate redundant view groups in your view
>   hierarchy when including one layout within another

and has an example too

> If your main layout is a vertical `LinearLayout` in which
>   two consecutive views can be re-used in multiple layouts, then the
>   re-usable layout in which you place the two views requires its own
>   root view. However, using another `LinearLayout` as the root for the
>   re-usable layout would result in a vertical `LinearLayout` inside a
>   vertical `LinearLayout`. The nested `LinearLayout` serves no real purpose
>   other than to slow down your UI performance.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093340/6891563), which will make you understand merge tag more.

### Problem in your layout

**For the child layout**

You put constraints on child elements inside `<merge` tag. That's not okay. Because that constraints are destroyed at run time when both child layout are merged inside your parent layout. (You tell me if you can do this without include tag, will your constraints work?)

**For parent layout**

Same for `<include` tag, you are giving constraints/custom attributes to `<include` tag, that will be lost, because `<merge` tag is joined to the root view, so you can not apply custom attributes to the `<include` with `<merge` tag.
That's why [Bahman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52343516/6891563) answer will work.

**Attributes on `<include` tag works** when you have root element inside child layout and **no `<merge` tag**.

### Conclusion

As this is clear, you are not using `<merge` and `<include`, as it should be. You have understand what `<include` and `<merge` tag do. So use them appropriately.

### If you ask solution

**[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) was introduced to solve complex layout. Not to increase complexity. So when you can do this easily with `LinearLayout` why to choose `Constraints`.**

**Parent Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/review_1"
        layout="@layout/view_movie_note"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/review_2"
        layout="@layout/view_movie_note"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**view_movie_note.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
     .../>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: output]

**I hope I could make you understand well.**

Answer (score 4):

Wrap `include` tags with `ConstraintLayout` tags then move attributes of `include` tags to these new `ConstraintLayout` tags:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/review_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/review_2">

                    <include  layout="@layout/view_movie_note"  />

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/review_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/review_1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

                       <include layout="@layout/view_movie_note" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: the inner `ConstraintLayout`s should possibly be `CardView`s (unless aligning by constraints, within these child-nodes).

Comment: @MartinZeitler No the tags which is included with `include` have some constraint attributes which is invalid in `cardView`

Comment: @MartinZeitler we do not know maybe included tags is used in some other layout and asker wants to keep them as is

Comment: that's why I wrote "unless" - while the whole question is about "how to create an overly complex solution to a simple problem" (that's why my answer only features alternate approaches).

Comment: @MartinZeitler I agree it has simpler answer. nested layouts should be avoided

Comment: Do you understand the whole point of the question is to keep the layout flat? If you add another constraints then just add it as root of the included view.

Comment: @DanieleSegato No i think the whole point of the question is to reuse the layouts. in this case you have two options to keep it flat OR reuse it. if you want to keep it flat you have to remove include tags and put all items in one layout. Because include & merge tags will remove and any layout attributes you put in those tags have no outcome.

Comment: To reuse layout you just have to avoid using merge tag. If you do you give up flatness. What you do here is give up flatness AND uselessly use merge when you could just have a plain standard layout that would be a lot more readable.

Comment: @DanieleSegato if you see the two added ConstraintLayouts has different attributes thus they could not replace merge tag because their attributes are not same

Comment: @DanieleSegato even if i avoid merge tag and use ConstraintLayout in place of merge tag also i have lost flatness

Comment: You can do the same directly on the include tag. It's useless to move the container there

Comment: @DanieleSegato it should be possible if you replace merge with Constraint layout then put attributes in two includes instead of two constraint layouts. did you have test this and worked?

Answer (score 2):

As a solution

Parent layout[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/review_1"
        layout="@layout/view_movie_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/review_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/review_2"
        layout="@layout/view_movie_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/review_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

view_movie_note [image: 2]]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_origin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/five_star_view_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPaddingTop="22dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="52dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/note_origin">

    <!--<FiveStarsView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/five_star_view"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />-->

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:contentPaddingLeft="15dp"
    app:contentPaddingRight="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/note_origin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grade"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

merge is a tag and not a ViewGroup, so all the parameter passed to the include will be ignored... You can flat this ViewGroup only with a duplicated layout, if you need to manage it, you can create a [Group](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group)... 
[XML attributes from merge layout to RelativeLayout via inflate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941038/xml-attributes-from-merge-layout-to-relativelayout-via-inflate)

Answer (score 0):

Some issues with your question:

1. As per android documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Include)

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the <include/> tag
>   So any constraint you put into include tag will be removed.

2. Any `android:id` in include will NOT be overridden if merge tag is used in your included layout.
3. Chaining and adding constraint works on views with different ids. So for including same view multiple times with equal weight will not work via include tag.

That being said, you can either copy paste the entire

Therefore, you can not use include in this fashion.

You are left with 3 options:

1. Use some other ViewGroup (LinearLayout and then constraint layout for example)
2. Copy paste the content of `include` layout with different ids of views
3. Modify `ConstraintLayout` code to support spread-chains so that entire included layout is copied horizontally.

IMO, 1st option is best if you have a small number of these layouts, 2nd option is best if you have only one layout (asked in question) and 3rd option is best if you have large number of layouts.