# How to use View Binding with Included Views?

Tags: android, binding

View Binding got released with v3.6.

Docs:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

My question is, does anyone know how to use view binding with included layouts?

Given Layout that includes another Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_header"
        layout="@layout/item_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to reference items inside of the item_header layout.

```
binder.my_header (<-- this just returns back the view)
binder.root (<-- this just returns back the root view)
```

Even if I add an id to the root of the item_header, such as id="@+id/parent_id" and try to reference that, I receive null pointer exceptions

```
binder.parentId (<-- I have access to views inside of the item_header, however, I receive exceptions. Says that "parentId" cannot be found)
```

How to reference the layout, `item_header`?

Comment: In the experiment that I just ran, `binder.my_header` is an `ItemHeaderBinding`, not a `View`. And I can reference widgets inside of that (e.g., `binder.my_header.foo`) without a problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare You the man! I didn't realize I could reference that. This works like a charm now. Do you mind posting your comment as an answer? I will accept.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616894/8040697

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's suppose that the layout in your question is `activity_main.xml`. The generated view binding class for it is `ActivityMainBinding`. Similarly, for `item_header.xml`, the generated view binding is `ItemHeaderBinding`.

If we pretend that `item_header.xml` has a `TextView` named `@+id/foo`, then you wind up with this chunk of Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(mainBinding.root)

    mainBinding.myHeader.foo.text = "this is a test"
  }
}
```

So, the `ActivityMainBinding` object should have a property with the `android:id` that you gave to the `<include>` — `myHeader` in this case. That should be an `ItemHeaderBinding`, as view binding appears to set up the nested binding object for the `<include>`. Since `myHeader` is an `ItemHeaderBinding`, you can then reference widgets on it just as you would if you directly inflated `ItemHeaderBinding` yourself.

Note that view binding appears to convert `lower_snake_case` into `lowerCamelCase`, so the `my_header` ID turns into `myHeader` in terms of the generated code.

Comment: This almost never works. Maybe one in a milllion layouts the Android Studio gods won't break and you can access your sub layout views and actually build but then the sub views won't update when you change them through code.

Comment: @behelit: FWIW, I have not had a particular problem with the technique, in a decent-sized app. Compose UI gets rid of all of this, of course.

Answer (score 6):

I have checked this problem in Java.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_header"
        layout="@layout/item_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

item_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.myHeader.foo.setText("this is a test");
    }
}}
```

I checked that it worked in my new project.
I hope it will help.