# ViewBinding - Included Layout Binding Resulting in Unresolved Reference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewbinding

I am implementing ViewBinding in one of my fragments. This fragment has a layout included like so:

```xml
...
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_sudf_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_sudf_continue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/eav_sudf_avatar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/l_sudf_details"
            layout="@layout/layout_sign_up_details_fields"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
...
```

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58730128/507313) but it also does not work.

The generated view binding class for the fragment has the binding inside, however, the type for the attribute is `View`. When I then reference the `View` using `binding.lSudfDetails` the type is `LayoutSignUpDetailFieldsBinding`. Where this type is coming from I can't work out as there is no generated class with that name however, I would expect it would assign it the proper binding type. Here is the attribute in the `FragmentSignUpDetailsBinding.java`.

```java
@NonNull
public final View lSudfDetails;
```

The bindings are all correctly setup however and it allow me to reference views within the nested layout but when I come to build I get unresolved reference errors. Lint does not complain when I reference them like this:

`binding.lSudfDetails.etSudfDob`

The compiler does fail however with errors such as this

> Unresolved reference: etSudfDob

The binding itself is created according to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments):

```
private var _binding : FragmentSignUpDetailsBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentSignUpDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.tvSudfWelcome.text = getString(R.string.sign_up_welcome,getString(R.string.app_name))
    binding.lSudfDetails.etSudfDob.setOnClickListener {
            showYearSelection()
    }
}
```

The `tvSudfWelcome` binding works its the nested binding it doesn't like.

Comment: is `layout_sign_up_details_fields`'s root tag is `<merge>`?

Comment: @SomeshKumar no its root is `LinearLayout`. I will change to merge to see if it makes a difference

Comment: No. it won't make any difference. Can you add some code.. how you're setting up view binding and then how you're accessing it?

Comment: @SomeshKumar I have added the code to the question

Comment: This looks perfect. Some people were facing problems with Android studio 3.6.0 regarding `ViewBinding`. Are you using the latest studio v 3.6.1  & gradle v 3.6.1?

Comment: Urgh, thanks @SomeshKumar. I updated from `3.6.0` to `3.6.1` and problem is resolved. Please post as an answer and I will mark as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Android Studio 3.6.0 sometimes gradle plugin fails to generate ViewBinding fields for included layouts. Please update to Android Studio 3.6.1 and gradle plugin version to 3.6.1.

Comment: Another one if you can help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/60549985/507313

Comment: im using the latest AS and still get this issue

Comment: @Jonathan Check if there are generated classes (after succefully build) inside  `app > build > generated > data_binding_base_class_source_out` folder?

Comment: Found out the issue, it was to do with the included xml layout not having a Layout viewgroup as its root one. I had a CardView as its root layout

Answer (score 3):

If someone has similar problem... I solved my problem with adding width and height for this included view. It helped, I do not have any idea why, but this would be my solution:

```
 <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/l_sudf_details"
        layout="@layout/layout_sign_up_details_fields"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a similar problem - I solved mine using:

execute gradle `task : prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel`

Answer (score 0):

changing the id name to the same as the layout name worked for me.
For eg:

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/layout_sign_up_details_fields"
            layout="@layout/layout_sign_up_details_fields"/>
```

I was working with databinding instead of viewbinding though