# ViewBinding - Different Flavor Layout Resource

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-flavors, android-viewbinding

I have a flavor that contains the same layout resource that is in my `main` source set. This is so it overrides the main one with the flavor specific one. I have done this in many places and it works fine until I introduced `ViewBinding`. For accuracy, the layout is a nested layout that is "included" in a fragment.

Here is the structure:

```
main
 - res 
 - - layout 
 - - - layout_sign_up_details_fields.xml
flavor 
 - res 
 - - layout 
 - - - layout_sign_up_details_fields.xml
```

I have a view, whose ID is `til_sudf_first_name`, in my flavor specific layout resource that I do not have in my main resource. This is intended. I can see this `View` is "bound" in my binding class by looking in the generated sources when running this build variant.

```java
@NonNull
public final TextInputLayout tilSudfFirstName;
```

Now the actual binding happens in a "base" class and is shared with child classes using the `protected` visibility modifier like so:

```kotlin
private var _binding : FragmentSignUpDetailsBinding? = null
protected val binding get() = _binding!!
protected val detailsBinding get() = binding.lSudfDetails
```

The problem is `detailsBinding` does not contain the view I require even though it's present in the generated class.

In addition, the other strange thing is even though there are views in the `main` layout file that are not in the flavor specific layout file, they are still included in the generated layout file.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? The workaround available to me is to use kotlin's synthetic view handling for this instance as I have been but I was trying to use the recommended approach

Comment: For now, I have had to go old school in my flavor dependent class and use `findViewById` to reference the flavor specific view.

Comment: It's 2023, and I can't find a better way than putting the id and setting layout_width, layout_height to 0 in other flavor specific layouts.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use one shared package name for your fragments and viewmodels:

```
main
 - java
 - - MainFragment (package com.rahul.sample.<..>)
 - - MainViewModel (package com.rahul.sample.<..>)

flavor
 - java
 - - FlavorFragment (package com.rahul.sample.<..>)
 - - FlavorViewModel (package com.rahul.sample.<..>)
```

This way the binding works.