# View Binding Issue with <Include> layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

I am using Android Studio 3.6.2 and enabled View Binding feature.

Facing difficulty while getting view added using **include** tag via binding.

> Toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="?toolbarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="0dp" />
```

> MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/merchant_navigation_graph" />
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AvailsTheme_DayNight)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        val toolbarBinding = binding.toolbar

        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question. see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616894/8040697

Answer (score 8):

You are accessing the included layout binding and not the toolbar which is inside the included layout. I can see that you did not give `MaterialToolbar` any ID. So you need to give toolbar object in XML an ID and include it in layout and then give the  an ID and then in your Kotlin file access it like `val toolbar = binding.includedLayout.toolbar`.  Also, You are accessing view before `setContentView(binding.root)` which is wrong. You need to set the layout before you try to access the views.

### Toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="?toolbarStyle" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="0dp" />
```

### MainActivity.xml

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            setTheme(R.style.AvailsTheme_DayNight)
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
            val toolbar = binding.includedLayout.toolbar
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I am getting toolBarBinding object when I do binding.toolbar. that is not giving toolbar instance.

Comment: Ohh, I see the real issue after you clarified. Check the updated answer it should definitely work.

Comment: @Pinakin Does this work?  Don't forget to mark an answer or give feedback if it doesn't work.

Comment: what if i have to access this in fragment?