# BaseFragment with viewbinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm, android-viewbinding

To use `viewbinding` in an android app I am basically creating base classes for `Activity` & `Fragment` to remove boilerplate of everytime writing inflating code.

**ACTIVITY:**

`BaseActivity` with `viewbinding`:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<VB : ViewBinding> : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = getViewBinding()
    }

    abstract fun getViewBinding(): VB

}
```

`MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding>() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        //we can directly use binding now and it works fine inside activity
        //binding.view.doSomething() 
    }

 override fun getViewBinding(): ActivityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}
```

**FRAGMENTS** :

`BaseFragment`:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VB : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

    var binding: VB? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = getViewBinding(view)
    }

    abstract fun getViewBinding(view: View): VB
}
```

`DemoFragment`:

```
class DemoFragment : BaseFragment<DemoFragmentBinding>() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //problem is here
        binding.txtData.text="Something"
    }

    override fun getViewBinding(view: View): DemoFragmentBinding = DemoFragmentBinding.bind(view)

}
```

demo_fragment.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.DemoFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello" />

</FrameLayout>
```

> Problem : Unable to access views using binding inside Demofragment. I don't know why it works with activity and not with fragment.

> 2nd way that I don't want todo:

*implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.1'*

```
class DemoFragment : Fragment(R.layout.demo_fragment) {

    lateinit var binding: DemoFragmentBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = DemoFragmentBinding.bind(view).apply {
            txtData.text = "Hello World"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the xml file for the fragment?

Comment: @Amin Updated the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewBinding - how to get binding for included layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730127/viewbinding-how-to-get-binding-for-included-layouts)

Comment: No it is not for included layouts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override `onCreateView` in BaseFragment and initialize the viewbinding

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    _binding = getViewBinding()
    return binding.root
}
```

Then change this line

```
override fun getViewBinding(view: View): DemoFragmentBinding = DemoFragmentBinding.bind(view)
```

with

```
override fun getViewBinding() = DemoFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

**BaseFragment**:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VB : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: VB? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = getViewBinding()
        return binding.root
    }

    abstract fun getViewBinding(): VB
}
```

**DemoFragment**:

```
class DemoFragment : BaseFragment<DemoFragmentBinding>() {

    override fun getViewBinding() = DemoFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.apply {
            txtData.text = "Something"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to implement this [factory abstraction](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm) with `ViewBinding`. I am sharing the implementation code below. I am using [`genrics`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html) here. If anyone needs further explanation, I am here for that. Make sure you have enabled `viewbinding` feature already into the `build.gradle` file. Then use the following `BaseFragment.kt` as your fragment abstraction.

**BaseFragment:**

```
typealias Inflate<T> = (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> T

abstract class BaseFragment<V: ViewBinding>(
    private val inflate: Inflate<V>
    ) : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var _binding: V
    val binding get() = _binding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

N:B: Know more about [typealias](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html).

**HomeFragment:**

```
// Implement the BaseFragment like below
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>(FragmentHomeBinding::inflate) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // usages by calling public variable 'binding' from base class
        binding.message.text = "update $value"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the documentation, I'm not sure if this breaks what you wanted with the abstract pattern in the `BaseFragment`, but I tested your code with this change and it worked. Only change was in the `DemoFragment`:

```
//Add this for the onCreateView implementation
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = DemoFragmentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), null, false)
        val view = binding!!.root
        return view
    }
```

Then I tested in `onViewCreated`:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //problem is here
        binding?.txtData?.text="Something"

    }
```

And it worked. The documentation I looked at was [this section](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments)

I think doing this still allows you to avoid some boilerplate, but the `onCreateView` override is going to be necessary for every fragment, because of the different viewbinding inflation (e.g. `DemoFragmentBinding.inflate etc etc`)

Comment: I can pass ``demo_fragment.xml`` in Fragment constructor params directly using `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0` without overriding onCreateView but I don't want to do that! Although thanks for the answer.

Comment: What do you mean you can pass layout_file?

Comment: Passing the layout xml doesn't give you viewbinding though. You need to inflate specifically using the ```DemoFragmentBinding.inflate(``` method

Answer (score 0):

Uses https://github.com/hoc081098/ViewBindingDelegate

```kotlin
abstract class BaseFragment<VB : ViewBinding>(@LayoutRes layoutId: Int) : Fragment(layoutId) {
  protected abstract val binding: VB
}


import com.hoc081098.viewbindingdelegate.*
class MainFragment: BaseFragment<FragmentMainBinding>(R.layout.fragment_main) {
  override val binding by viewBinding()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    abstract class BaseFragment<VB : ViewBinding>(
    private val bindingInflater: (inflater: LayoutInflater) -> VB
) : Fragment() {

    private var frg_binding: VB? = null

    val binding: VB
        get() = frg_binding as VB

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        frg_binding = bindingInflater.invoke(inflater)

        if (frg_binding == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Binding can't be null")
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a fragment need a ViewModel, this is my BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VB : ViewBinding, VM : ViewModel>(
    private val inflate: (layoutInflater: android.view.LayoutInflater, container: android.view.ViewGroup?, attachToRoot: Boolean) -> VB,
    private val viewModelClass: Class<VM>
) : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: VB? = null

    protected val binding: VB get() = _binding!!

    lateinit var viewModel: VM

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: android.view.LayoutInflater,
        container: android.view.ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: android.os.Bundle?
    ): android.view.View? {
        _binding = inflate.invoke(inflater, container, false)
        return _binding?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: android.view.View, savedInstanceState: android.os.Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupViewModel()
        initData()
        loadData()
        handleClickInView()
    }


    private fun setupViewModel() {
        viewModel = getViewModel(viewModelClass)
    }

    private fun <VM : ViewModel> getViewModel(modelClass: Class<VM>): VM {
        return ViewModelProvider(this)[modelClass]
    }

    // Override this method to initialize observers in your activity
    abstract fun initData()

    // Override this method to handle load data in your view
    abstract fun loadData()


    // Override this method to handle all click event in your view
    abstract fun handleClickInView()

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

and implement it in a fragment

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding, HomeViewModel>(
    FragmentHomeBinding::inflate,
    HomeViewModel::class.java
) {}
```