# Android: no view IDs are available inside a ScrollView for ViewBinding. How to access?

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-viewbinding

I am trying to convert an existing project with findViewByIds over to ViewBinding.  All of the view IDs outside of the ScrollView are available in Android Studio for use with "binding.viewId..."  The problem is none of the views with IDs that are within the ScrollView are available for use with "binding.viewID..."  So I am not able to access ImageViews that are within two <include layouts that are within a ViewFlipper in the layout.  The simple ViewFlipper toggles between an up arrow ImageView and a down arrow ImageView. The ViewFlipper has an <include layout for the up ImageView and a second <include layout for the down ImageView. The ViewFlipper is inside a LinearLayout and the LinearLayout is inside the ScrollView.

```
//Activity
private ActivityEditBinding binding;

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityEditBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);

// activity_edit.xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".AddorUpdateCardActivity">
 ...
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"  >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/secondLinearLayout"
    ...  >        
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lowerVFRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/expandVF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"  >

        <include layout="@layout/expand_more_act_edit"
            android:id="@+id/expandMore"  />

        <include layout="@layout/expand_less_act_edit"
            android:id="@+id/expandLess"  />

     </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

// expand_more_act_edit.xml
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/downArrow"
android:layout_width="45dp"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:contentDescription="sd"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more"  />

<!-- the down arrow -->
```

I confirmed that the autogenerated ViewBinding classes have been created.  Below is where I am trying to attach a ClickListener to the downArrow but I can't access the downArrow reference.  What am I missing here?

```
***Android Studio says "Cannot resolve symbol 'expandMore'***
binding.expandMore.downArrow.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        
    // change the down arrow to the up arrow and show the 1-20 EditText lines.
    expandVF.setDisplayedChild(expandVF.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.expandLess)));
    moreViewStub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
});
```

Does ViewBinding not work within a ScrollView?  What am I missing here?

Comment: "I confirmed that the autogenerated ViewBinding classes have been created" -- have you looked at what they contain? I have used view binding with `<include>` successfully, so I am uncertain why `expandMore` would not be in your binding.

Comment: I looked in the class, it contains:  "@NonNull public final ExpandMoreActEditBinding expandMore;" and "@NonNull public final ViewFlipper expandVF;" and "this.expandVF = expandVF;" and "this.expandMore = expandMore;"   So appears to be good.

Comment: @CommonsWare So in the Activity, I am able to access all of the view IDs using "binding.viewID..." except for the the IDs that are inside a <ScrollView/>.  And the expandVF and expandMore  are inside of a <Linearlayout/> and that is inside the ScrollView.  The ScrollView and the LinearLayout look correct in the autogenerated binding class.  Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: "except for the the IDs that are inside a <ScrollView/>. And the expandVF and expandMore are inside of a <Linearlayout/> and that is inside the ScrollView" -- that seems to conflict with what you wrote in [your first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67779226/android-how-to-access-include-layout-in-a-viewflipper-with-viewbinding?noredirect=1#comment119803763_67779226). So, I am uncertain what to tell you.

Comment: @CommonsWare All of the views appear to be set up correctly in the autogenerated binding class.  But when I try to add "binding.viewID..." in the Activity for an ID that is contained within the ScrollView, that ID text does not automatically appear.  And that is when Studio shows the 'Cannot resolve symbol error' and the ID text is colored red.

Answer (score 3):

*View binding will generate camelCase id  from id that you have provided in your layout.If your view id is already in camelCase(expandVF) in your layout,sometimes android studio won't recognize that because layout view id and binding class view id are same.that may produce 'Cannot resolve symbol error'.*

*so instead of expandVF,expandMore,expandLess use expand_vf,expand_more,expand_less.Rebuild and run,may work.*

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I will change and then rebuild based on your feedback!

Comment: okay.let me know whether it's works or not.@AJW

Comment: No luck.  I changed the IDs to your suggestions and re-built the project.  I am still not able to access any of the layout IDs in the ScrollView when I am in the Activity and I type "binding.someIDInsideOfTheScrollView".  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: everything working as expected when i run your code.So split the layout and Try to find issue like  first add Relative layout and scrollview without anything into it ,then check scrollview binding class id   in activity  then add viewFlipper only  without include tag then find it in activity after all run your  relative layout (secondLinearLayout)as root layout .in this way you can find issue.@AJW

Comment: I changed the layout IDs as you suggested and deleted all other layout views and kept just the ScrollView section.  I deleted the previous autogenerated java class.  Then I commented out all previous "...findViewById()".  Then cleaned and re-built the project, synced the project with gradle files and then invalidate caches/restart.  Voila! I was able to finally access the IDs inside the ScrollView and the ViewFlipper <include>.  Haven't rebuilt the entire xml yet but hope to have enough to keep adding to the initial ScrollView section.  Thx, answer upvoted and bounty awarded.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to use** `binding.expandVF` instead of directly using `expandVF`
and to use id of layout which have been included, you need to use `binding.expandLess.ID_YOU_WANT_TO_USE`

Comment: The error is on the code line to set the OnClickListener.  binding.expandVF or binding.expandMore are not working.

Comment: Yes because you are trying to directly access the id ... I think you just need to write binding before that...if are you using viewBinding

Comment: I tried binding.expandVF and I tried binding.expandMore.  See above.  Neither one is working.

Comment: You need to make <layout/> as the parent if you want to use viewBinding

Comment: <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    
HERE_YOUR_LAYOUT_SHOULD_BE  </layout>

Comment: That is for DataBinding.  I just want to use ViewBinding.

Comment: have you enabled view binding by doing this -> buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

Comment: Yes, I mentioned above that all of the autogenerated binding java classes have been created.

Comment: Nice then inflating layout in onCreateView like this -> private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

Comment: Reference -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: I read android developer reference thanks.  And you provide Kotlin.  My question is for Android code.

Comment: could you please share your java code, so that I can help you with the exact answer?

Comment: I put all of the code above in the question.

Answer (score 1):

for databinding

in `activity.java`

```
private ActivityEditBinding binding;

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_edit);
    
}
```

in `activity_edit.xml`

```
<layout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".AddorUpdateCardActivity">//...
<ScrollView
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lowerVFRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/expandVF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"  >

        <include layout="@layout/expand_more_act_edit"
            android:id="@+id/expandMore"  />

        <include layout="@layout/expand_less_act_edit"
            android:id="@+id/expandLess"  />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

now

```
binding.expandMore.downArrow.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        
});
```

for **ViewBinding** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58730128/12709358)

Comment: Hi, I'm not interested in using data binding. I specifically used ViewBinding.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I don't see the problem in the code so I'm guessing maybe the Android build tool version is quite old - ViewBinding doesn't work very well

Try to update the build tools to the latest version 4.2.0 in `build.gradle` of project

```
dependencies {
   // At least it should be from 4.0.0 
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
}
```

And distributionUrl in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
# tools.build 4.2.0 requruired gradle distribution at least 6.7.1+
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-bin.zip
```

Change the viewBinding declaration if it is different from the code below:

```
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Then Clean-Rebuild your project.

Check out [Compatibility Android Gradle plugin - Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

Comment: Thanks for ideas.  I had relatively new build tool, wrapper.properties and had the viewBinding declaration.  Will include those in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

convert your `activity_edit.xml`, `expand_less_act_edit.xml`, and  `expand_more_act_edit.xml` layout into data binding by wrapping into layout tag.

your `activity_edit.xml` will look like

```
 <layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".AddorUpdateCardActivity">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lowerVFRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  >

    <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/expandVF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"  >

        <include layout="@layout/expand_more_act_edit"
            android:id="@+id/expandMore"  />

        <include layout="@layout/expand_less_act_edit"
            android:id="@+id/expandLess"  />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </layout>
```

your `expand_more_act_edit.xml` will look like

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/downArrow"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:contentDescription="sd"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more"  />
</layout>
```

your main class to access the `ImageView` will be.

```
private ActivityEditBinding binding;

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_edit);
//binding.expandMore.downArrow this is how you will gonna access the view. now do what ever you want with this.
    
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not interested in using data binding.  I specifically used ViewBinding.

Comment: then just remove the layout tag from all xmls. rest would be same. instead of using util use ActivityEditBinding class to inflate the view and hold binding instance.

Comment: I don't have a layout tag in my xmls.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was talking about the solution that I gave for your problem. The rest is Simple just follow the java code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have missed `ViewFlipper` closing tag and there are other layout issues in xml. Check if that is the issue.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".AddorUpdateCardActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"  >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondLinearLayout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lowerVFRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"  >

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/expandVF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"  >

        <include layout="@layout/expand_more_act_edit"
            android:id="@+id/expandMore"  />

        <include layout="@layout/expand_less_act_edit"
            android:id="@+id/expandLess"  />
        </ViewFlipper>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've corrected some but not sure since I don't know the whole layout. Since there are some ellipses in the layout you have provided. Other than that `ViewBinding` has no issues with `ScrollView` AFAIK.