# ViewBinding of included library will not generated

Tags: android-viewbinding

Im kinda stuck here:

We have a UI Component library we're using all over the place in the project. Also the viewbinding get generated for those layouts which works fine.

I stuck when i try to include those layouts in the main project in another layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
   <include id="@+id/includedLayoutFromLib" layout="@layout/someLibraryLayout"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I've read about how to include a layout (I do not make use of merge here).

I cannot access the included views:

```
 binding.includedLayoutFromLib.title
```

I would expect "title" to be accessible from the included binding when an ID for the include is set. All views have IDs also in the included one

Is this a bug or what i miss here ?

thx

Comment: Yeah this one is interesting. I have a similar situation where my `binding.includedLayoutFromLib` would be of type `View`, and not the binding. Weirdly, the binding exists for `includedLayoutFromLib`, but `binding.includedLayoutFromLib` is just not referencing it.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228371459 there is an opened issue here

Answer (score 1):

I also face the same problem,it`s very very ...,for change bing.view.findViewById(R.id.test) maybe work.

Answer (score 0):

I did quick check and had similar case I think, separate module with layouts, included those in other module's layout and it all worked nice. Perhaps you could check gradle configuration if you have

```
android {
   buildFeatures { viewBinding = true } 
}
```

set in both modules.
Also I would start wirh clean build, gradle sync or even android studio invalidate cache / restart just to rule out some junk build files as source of problem.

Also other question: is this UI Component lib precompiled or is it a module in your project. From what I see it also should work but perhaps it would require some extra configuration in such case?

Comment: You talk about modules, i guess you mean gradle modules. That works just fine. We have a UI Component Library on a internal maven repo and it just added via implementation "library:name:version" and it ignores to generate bindings. All post who show how it works never show dis kind of scenario which is kind of common in larger projects

Comment: Oh I see your case. Well I don't have code yet to test it but in your position I would start from trying `api` instead of `implementation ` as it gives you more access to internal lib files and as bindings are generated in this particular lib (they may be treated as some internal thing) you may not see them because you use too weak dependencies configuration.

Comment: Ohh, that may be at least an option to try, will give feedback

Answer (score 0):

Since viewing binding works for me like the way you have mentioned, I would recommend **Clean Project** then **invalidate caches/restart**, and then **Rebuild Project**. What version of the android studio are you using?

Comment: Im on AS 4.2 and cleaned the caches an so on.

Comment: It would be a long step, but if nothing else work just try removing binding and then enabling it again and can you just share the library xml.