# Android ViewBinding <merge> layout issues

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I defined a layout in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <eo.view.batterymeter.BatteryMeterView
        android:id="@+id/batteryMeter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/colorInputView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/include_battery_meters_with_indicator" />

    <eo.view.colorinput.ColorInputView
        android:id="@+id/colorInputView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/batteryMeter" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this's the layout file included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_color_edit">

    <eo.view.batterymeter.BatteryMeterView
        android:id="@+id/chargingBatteryMeter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/batteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/criticalBatteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/batteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/batteryMeter" />

    <eo.view.batterymeter.BatteryMeterView
        android:id="@+id/criticalBatteryMeter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/chargingBatteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/unknownBatteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/chargingBatteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/chargingBatteryMeter" />

    <eo.view.batterymeter.BatteryMeterView
        android:id="@+id/unknownBatteryMeter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/chargingBatteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/batteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/criticalBatteryMeter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/chargingBatteryMeter" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/indicatorBatteryMeterGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="chargingBatteryMeter,criticalBatteryMeter,unknownBatteryMeter" />

</merge>
```

In the source code i deflate the layout:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityColorEditBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityColorEditBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root

    setContentView(view)

    setupActionBar()
    setupBatteryMeters()
    setupColorInput()
}
```

For some reason items inside included file are not *bound* and thus references to such items are not working, for example in this method `binding.indicatorBatteryMeterGroup` is not recognized:

```
private fun setupBatteryMeters() {
    when (colorType) {
        ColorType.INDICATOR -> {
            setupIndicatorBatteryMeters()
            binding.batteryMeter.isInvisible = true
            binding.indicatorBatteryMeterGroup.isVisible = true
        }
        else -> {
            setupBattery(binding.batteryMeter)
            binding.indicatorBatteryMeterGroup.isVisible = false
            binding.batteryMeter.isVisible = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `include` element an ID:

```xml
<include layout="@layout/include_battery_meters_with_indicator"
    android:id="@+id/battery_meters" />
```

Then you can access them as a property of a property of your binding, for instance, `binding.batteryMeters.criticalBatteryMeter`.

Don't put an ID on the `merge` element. IIRC, this causes it not to work properly. The ID has to be on the `include`.

Comment: It seems to work but on build I got this: 
`e: ColorEditActivity.kt: (123, 38): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type IncludeBatteryMetersWithIndicatorBinding?`

Comment: Sounds like you have defined that property as nullable when it should be `lateinit` non-nullable.

Comment: As you can see in the code above is defined as `lateinit` as you suggest

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. I would consider it a bug of view binding, but there is a work-around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730127/viewbinding-how-to-get-binding-for-included-layouts). I'll delete this answer later. My solution works when the child is not a `merge` element. See part 2 of the top answer on that other question for how to handle it when the child is a `merge` element.